# How to transform dictionary data into a string vector?

Tags: python, feature-engineering, encoding

I have `key`,`value` data where each record is in a Python string.
An example record looks like this:

```
record = {
    'first_name': 'john',
    'last_name': 'doe',
    'age': '50',
}
```

To encode this into a neural net, I would like to firs have this data as a string vector. A sample output is like this:

```
"first_name john last_name doe age 50"
```

How can I make this transformation?

Comment: Does first_name, last_name, age come in order as you wrote or it can be in any order, like **"last_name doe age 50 first_name john"**?

Comment: @AnkitSeth the representation which I wrote is one of the possible views of the record since Python dictionary's key/value pairs are unordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want output in any order, do this-

```
>>> string_vector = ''
>>> for k,v in record.items():
        string_vector += k + ' ' + v + ' '

>>> string_vector = string_vector.rstrip(' ')
>>> string_vector 
'first_name john last_name doe age 50'
```